# В файле медиа запросов не работает адаптация для смартфона

Tags: css, media-queries

В одном и том же файле делают медиа запрос для:

```css
@media all and (max-width: 1930px){
}
```

Он работает и все в порядке, но следом начинаю делать следующий:

```css
@media all and (max-width: 415px){
 .golden_title h1{
  font-size:200px;
 }
}
```

и он никак не работает, страница не реагирует(через <kbd>F12</kbd> изменяю ширину страницы)

Comment: напишите так : @media (max-width:415px){style}

Comment: У меня вопрос, а что означает сие `@media all and (max-width: 1930px)`, будь другом расшифруй... ????

Comment: all это говорит о том что ты спрашиваешь обо всех типах запросов ...но по сути надо всего один ...

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский, ...))))))))

Comment: @Air  что за юмор то ? я не прав ?

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский, прав на все сто...Просто я хотел узнать, что именно хочет автор реализовать....

Comment: @Air вопрос бесполезный

Comment: @Air  где Артур ?

Comment: @Павел Варшавский, не знаю... Сам его сто лет не видел.... На сколько знаю работает над каким то собственным проектом...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно, это происходит из-за отсутствия в Html-файле данной строчки.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Это вопрос или утверждение?

Comment: Перефразировал. Теперь утверждение)

Comment: не сработало(((

Comment: А какие стили заданы у `.golden_title h1` до медиа-запросов?

Comment: все получислось, всем спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, после вашего запроса вы перезаписываете стили для `.golden_title h1`. Проверьте, находятся ли ваши медиа-запросы в конце файла?

Answer (score -1):

Медиа запросы в твоём случае должны идти от большего @media (max-width: 1930px) к меньшему @media (max-width: 415px) сверху-вниз. Чтобы срабатывали нужные стили. Пример этот код:

```css
@media (max-width: 1930px) {
.golden_title h1 {
  font-size:200px;
 }
}
@media (max-width: 415px) {
.golden_title h1 {
  font-size:20px;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 1931px) {
.golden_title h1 {
  font-size:222px;
 }
}
.golden_title h1 {
    color: gold;
}
body {
    color: gold;
    background-color: #1A237E;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="golden_title">
<h1>Тест Золотого Названия</h1>
</div>
```